# JavaScript & CSS: How to log position of a div between css translate start and end

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

Basically I need to perform collision and rebound animation for three balls moving randomly within a frame/container, placed similar to that in the picture below.

[image]

To check whether the ball is colliding with anything I need to track each position of the div during the translate state in css using javascript.
Using `getBoundingClientRect()` I will only get the final position of the div, but I need to track/log down each point of the path followed by the div when we use css translate.

I will be using plain angular animation, and I am not planning to add additional jQuery for this task.

Here is a sample demo which I tried on browser console, it is helping me move the ball randomly but they gets overlapped sometime, which I need to rebound when a ball touch either the edge of the container or surface of another ball.

```js
function getRandomInt(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}

var anim2 = document.getElementsByClassName("animation1")[0];
var anim1 = document.getElementsByClassName("animation2")[0];
var anim4 = document.getElementsByClassName("animation3")[0];

function action() {

  var randomNumMin1 = getRandomInt(-100, 100);
  var randomNumMin2 = getRandomInt(-100, 100);
  var randomNumMin3 = getRandomInt(-100, 100);

  var randomNumMax1 = getRandomInt(-100, 100);
  var randomNumMax2 = getRandomInt(-100, 100);
  var randomNumMax3 = getRandomInt(-100, 100);

  var num1 = `translate(${randomNumMin1}px, ${randomNumMax1}px)`;
  var num2 = `translate(${randomNumMin2}px, ${randomNumMax2}px)`;
  var num4 = `translate(${randomNumMin3}px, ${randomNumMax3}px)`;

  anim1.style.transition = 'all 3s';
  anim1.style.transform = num1;

  anim2.style.transition = 'all 3s';
  anim2.style.transform = num2;

  anim4.style.transition = 'all 3s';
  anim4.style.transform = num4;
}

action()
var interval = setInterval(() => {
  action()
}, 3000)
```

```css
[class*=animation] {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background: red;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="animation1"></div>
<div class="animation2"></div>
<div class="animation3"></div>
```

Help needed.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably do something like polling to check whether the two balls collide/intersect each other?

```
function collides(ball1, ball2){
  var obj1 = ball1.getBoundingClientRect();
  var obj2 = ball2.getBoundingClientRect();

  if (obj1.left < obj2.left + obj2.width  && obj1.left + obj1.width  > obj2.left &&
        obj1.top < obj2.top + obj2.height && obj1.top + obj1.height > obj2.top) {
    // change transform / reverse etc.
  }
  else{
    // not collided yet
  }
}
```

The Element.getBoundingClientRect() method returns the size of an element and its position relative to the viewport.
[MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect)

Answer (score 0):

So basically you need to animate balls with JS instead of CSS and detect collisions on each animation frame. So your code should look something like this:

```js
const balls = [{
    $el: document.getElementsByClassName("animation1")[0],
    r: 25, // ball radius
    vs: 0.1, // speed in pixels per frame
  },
  {
    $el: document.getElementsByClassName("animation2")[0],
    r: 25, // ball radius
    vs: 0.3, // speed in pixels per frame
  },
  {
    $el: document.getElementsByClassName("animation3")[0],
    r: 25, // ball radius
    vs: 0.5, // speed in pixels per frame
  }
];

function isColliding(ball1, ball2) {
  const a = ball1.r + ball2.r;
  const dx = ball1.$el.offsetLeft - ball2.$el.offsetLeft;
  const dy = ball1.$el.offsetTop - ball2.$el.offsetTop;
  return a > Math.sqrt((dx ** 2) + (dy ** 2));
}

function tick() {
  // Change positions
  balls.forEach((ball) => {
    ball.$el.style.y += ball.vs;
  });

  // Detect collisions
  for (let i = 0; i < balls.length - 1; i++) {
    for (let j = i + 1; j < balls.length; j++) {
      if (isColliding(balls[i], balls[j])) {
        // Collision detected
      }
    }
  }
  
  requestAnimationFrame(tick);
}

requestAnimationFrame(tick);
```

```css
[class*=animation] {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="animation1"></div>
<div class="animation2"></div>
<div class="animation3"></div>
```

Comment: Hi, your solution looks fine for me, let me try. BTW I have updated the question a bit.

Comment: @AnkitKumarSingh this is just a common approach. Basically you have some entities list or maybe even manager and on every screen frame you are performing some calculations or just applying a state (if you change it somewhere outside of tick function, for example, in some setTimeout callback or on user interaction)